# Why does console.log stop errors in javascript Library?

Tags: javascript

I have been toying with creating a small library for a web app I am working on. In creating this library, I can enter a log statement at the top of the script, and everything below works fine. However, if I remove the top console.log statement, I get errors. Code is below. Errors are:

```
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable TestFirst
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        console.log('starting');
        'use strict';
        function define_TestFirst()  {
            function TestFirst () {};
            return TestFirst;
        }

        if (typeof(TestFirst) === 'undefined') {
            console.log('defined');
            TestFirst = define_TestFirst();
            TestFirst.prototype.test = function () {
                console.log('TestFirst object created.');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('TestFirst library already defined!');
        }
    })();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `"use strict"` must be the first statement of your function in order to be used. It's ignored otherwise.

Now, I guess that you see the problem:
The problem is not about removing the top `console.log`, it's about `use strict` being no longer ignored.

The problem with your script running in strict mode is that any variable must be declared first :

```
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable TestFirst
```

Means that you need to add the `var` statement at **`var`**`TestFirst = define_TestFirst();`

Comment: This raises a new question. I call the library in my page like so:    

    var tf = new TestFirst(); tf.test();. 

Why does this work without 'use strict'?

Comment: You completely lost me on that comment, but that very well may be due to my lack of knowledge. Can you expand your comment, or be more explicit about your meaning, or possibly point me to a reference?

Comment: @tjcertified I suspect two reasons: first off all, you are using a named function `function named(){}` (as opposed to `var anonymous function(){};`). The difference is that named functions are parsed prior to any other statement within their scope so they are "early available". See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ruhsuhz/1) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). On 2nd thought, you didn't say how you are importing you're lib and calling functions. Just to be sure: "use strict" is not required to use strictly declared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you did not *declare* `TestFirst` with `var` but assign a value to it (or use `window.TestFirst = ...`):

```
TestFirst = define_TestFirst();
```

You want strict mode, but having the `console.log()` before the `use strict` causes the `use strict` to not enable strict mode.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement
>   "use strict"; (or 'use strict';) before any other statements.